# iOS: Binary Framework using Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch

If I make binary framework using swift, will it support objective C projects and  what will be minimum supported version? is there any other drawbacks compare to objective c framework?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `Binary frameworks` in Swift will support Obj-C projects. Please ensure Obj-C related settings in Build Settings of Framework project are enabled. It will be enabled by default to create bridging header to inter-operate with Obj-C.

**Minimum supported OS Version**

With Swift ABI stability achieved in Swift 5 and now, module stability in place, there is no need to ship Swift source code while sharing the frameworks. If we want to share the library, Binary framework (`xcframework`) can be created and shipped without worrying about Swift compiler version incompatibility errors.

Since binary frameworks is dependent on module stability, and in turn, ABI stability, it needs Swift standard library in OS itself. Apple started including Swift standard library in OS when Xcode 10.2 was released, in which Swift 5 was supported. It means, iOS < 12.2 will not have Swift standard library. So, in case of iOS version < 12.2, all swift apps will have their own runtime library included in it. In case of pure Obj-C projects running in iOS < 12.2, ensure "`Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries`" to Yes in Build settings. Otherwise, it will crash in runtime. So, with respect to OS versions, we see this as the only limitation.

I was able to run a pure Obj-C project using Binary Framework in Swift, even in iOS 9 simulator.

**Advantages of using Binary Framework**

Binary Framework in swift can be created for all devices, simulators and for all platforms (iOS, MacOS, watchOS, tvOS). It's a single library for all platforms.

We need not ship actual swift source code in framework.It has resolved Swift compiler incompatibility issues.

Interoperability with Obj-C is simple and effortless and can't vouch same on vice-versa.

Hope it helps.